# Importing module moment-lunar is not working

Tags: javascript, momentjs

If you write the JavaScript code below, will get an error.

```
import moment from "moment";
import "moment-lunar";
```

error

```
moment-lunar.js:97 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
  at Object.<anonymous> (moment-lunar.js:97)
  at Object../node_modules/moment-lunar/moment-lunar.js (moment-lunar.js:181)
  at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
```

moment-lunar.js 97 line code is as follows.

```
moment.fn.solar = function (isLeanMonth) {      <--- This is 97 line
    isLeanMonth = isLeanMonth === true;
    var days = lunarMonthday[this.year() - lunarMonthday[0]];
    var leap = getBitInt(days, 4, 13);
    var offset = 0;
    var loopend = leap;
    ......
}
```

Can the question make the moment variable available to the module in the "moment-lunar" module?

Comment: Theoretically you shouldn't even import `moment` as it's marked as a dependency in  the `moment-lunar` library, which imports it. Maybe the 2 imports are clashing? Try removing your import of `moment`

Comment: Hmm, I think I got an idea. Are you using `webpack` by any chance? Aren't you getting a warning when compiling such as **Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted**?